# perl - using given gives errors

Tags: perl, nagios

I'm almost done with a nagios plugin and I'm using this [guide.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-nagios-plugins-with-perl-on-ubuntu-12-10) I'm getting error's though and I'm not sure why.

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $warn = 20;
my $crit = 50;
my $percent_down = 10;
my $percent_up = 90;
my $err = "error";

given ($percent_down) {
        when ($percent_down lt $warn) { print "OK - $percent_up% UP"; exit 0;}
        when ($percent_down ge $warn && lt $crit ) { print "WARNING - $percent_down% DOWN"; exit (1);}
        when ($percent_down ge $crit) { print "CRITICAL - $percent_down% DOWN"; exit (2);}
        default { print "UNKNOWN - $err "; exit (3);}
}
```

I get syntax error's starting at `given ($percent_down) {` at the `") {"` then at `";}"` on every line after that.

Comment: At a glance -- `$percent_down ge $warn && lt $crit` -- you can't do `$var ge $c1 && lt $c2`.  Those `&& lt` don't mean anything. Make full conditions, `$var ge $c1 && $var lt $c2`.  And watch for precedence.  If those are indeed numbers, use `>=`, `<` etc.

Comment: Use `<` and `>=` for numbers, not `lt` and `ge`. (For example, `9 ge 10` is true.)

Comment: Did you enable the `given` feature? Do you need to? `use feature "switch"; ...`

Comment: That it is experimental is said, but why? Read here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Experimental-Details-on-given-and-when

Comment: I suggest that you ignore that guide. It is a misuse of `given` `when`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `given`, you need

```
no if $] >= 5.018, warnings => "experimental::smartmatch";
use feature qw( switch );
```

---

Also,

```
$percent_down ge $warn && lt $crit
```

should be

```
$percent_down ge $warn && $percent_down lt $crit
```

---

Now for the problems you didn't ask about.

`lt` and `ge` are for comparing strings. Use `<` and `>=` to compare numbers. (For example, `9 ge 10` is true.)

---

Finally, you shouldn't use `given`-`when`. It's an experimental feature that *will* be removed or changed in a backwards-incompatible manner in the future.

---

Once you fix the above problems and remove the redundant checks, you are left with the following:

```
if ($percent_down < $warn) {
   print "OK - $percent_up% UP";
   exit(0);
}

if ($percent_down < $crit) {
   print "WARNING - $percent_down% DOWN";
   exit(1);
}

print "CRITICAL - $percent_down% DOWN";
exit(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

For a number of reasons you are best advised to avoid `given` and `when`. Even once you have enabled the feature correctly you will get another slew of warning messages telling you that the feature is experimental, and in any case you are not using the facilities that the feature is useful for -- primarily smartmatching, which is also experimental

The final `when` block can never be entered because all possibilities are covered by the preceding conditions

I recommend that you write it using an `if` `elsif` `else` sequence like this. I believe that it's more readable this way

```
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $warn = 20;
my $crit = 50;

my $percent_down = 10;
my $percent_up   = 100 - $percent_down;

if ( $percent_down < $warn ) {
    print "OK - $percent_up% UP";
    exit 0;
}
elsif ( $percent_down < $crit ) {
    print "WARNING - $percent_down% DOWN";
    exit 1;
}
else {
    print "CRITICAL - $percent_down% DOWN";
    exit 2;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Thank's for the comments, I got it.

```
if ($percent_down lt $warn) {
        print "OK - $percent_up% UP";
        exit 0;
        } elsif ($percent_down ge $warn && $percent_down lt $crit ) {
        print "WARNING - $percent_down% DOWN";
        exit 1;
        } elsif ($percent_down ge $crit) {
        print "CRITICAL - $percent_down% DOWN";
        exit 2;
        } else {
        print "UNKNOWN - $err ";
        exit 3;
        }
```

Comment: Please *use the answers* that you've asked for. And when you've made a choice you should select one of them and accept it.

Comment: There were no other answers at the time.